# Conectar PHP 8 con SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, apache, php8

He estado tratando de conectar PHP 8 con SQL SERVER, ya descargue los drivers de Microsoft y los coloque en la carpeta ext, pero me encuentro con dos problemas:

1. El PHP 8 no tiene un php.ini en la carpeta, sino que tiene dos archivos php.ini-development y php.ini-production, en ambos ya incluí las lineas y reinicie el servicio de Apache pero sigue sin reconocerme las funciones y me da error "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in D:\Programas\LocalServices\Apache 2.4\htdocs\proceso.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Programas\LocalServices\Apache 2.4\htdocs\proceso.php on line 9"

   ; CONFIGURACIÓN SQL SERVER
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll

Comment: Puedes mostrar también el código que usas para conectarte, no solo el error. ayudará más a a darte una respuesta satisfactoria.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionar, lo dejo por si alguien mas tiene el mismo problema, los pasos que hice fueron los siguientes (ojo que todo esto fue porque yo instale manualmente los binarios de Apache 2.4 y PHP 8, no use WAMP, MAMP, XAMP, etc):

- Agregue a las variables de entorno globales la dirección de la carpeta PHP.
- Descimenté las líneas en los archivos que reconocían la dirección de los drivers (carpeta ext) en los archivos php.ini-development y php.ini-production.
- Instalé los archivos en: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 y los pase a la carpeta **`...php/ext`**.
- Agregue estas líneas en **`hhtpd.conf`** para que Apache reconociera el PHP:

  ```
  PHPIniDir "D:/Programas/LocalServices/php"
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
  LoadModule php_module "D:/Programas/LocalServices/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
  ```